# How do I establish a UDP connection after a TCP connection?

Tags: sockets, tcp, network-programming, udp

Hi guys I'm currently developing a C project in which we basically need to connect N clients to a server through a proxy. I'm doing the first connecting using the TCP protocol. After this, the client may request a file download using UDP. Do I need to have another socket listening to another port and connect the client again to this port or is this an incorrect way of thinking?

Comment: Why are you using UDP for the file transfer?  Why not just use the TCP connection you already have?

Comment: Because my university teacher requires that our program is able to download through both UDP and TCP. @RemyLebeau

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TCP and UDP communicate in very different ways.  You'll need a separate socket for each 
one.

You'll probably want to use the TCP socket to communicate the UDP port to use.

Comment: So the best way to do this is to send the port to the client after the download request in which the client has to connect to the server again? @dbush

Comment: note that you can bind a TCP and UDP socket to the same port number.  they would be identified as separate sockets in your program, but externally it could all be the same port number

Comment: @LuisSilva Yes, the TCP communication should include a UDP port that one party will listen on.  Then one end will create a UDP socket on that port and wait, and the other will create a UDP socket and send to the remote endpoint.

Comment: @SamMason So, is best practice to have a process / thread waiting for a UDP connection in the same port?

Comment: @LuisSilva Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Comment: @LuisSilva I'd not like to comment on "best practice", but not many protocols work naturally over both TCP and UDP.  one example is DNS and should be available on port 53 on TCP and UDP.  as another example QUIC/HTTP3 is slowly gaining traction and by default uses the same port number for UDP as TCP, but has provisions to use a different port number